# How do I use WebRequest and HttpWebResponse in C# to navigate to an authentication url and login to a website?

Tags: c#, api, rest, authentication, mindmapping

I am trying to use the MindMeister API (as documented here: http://www.mindmeister.com/developers/authentication) to make a desktop application. So far, I am able to generate an authentication url as documented on their developer's guide with an api key an shared secret, which ends up looking something like this: http://www.mindmeister.com/services/auth/?api_key=abc123&perms=delete&api_sig=zxy987

If I copy and paste that url into my browser, it takes me to their log in page. Once I log in, then it says my application has been authenticated and I can proceed with my application, which then allows me to start using the different REST API methods. I would like to navigate to that authentication url and login to MindMeister programmatically without having to copy and paste the authentication url into the browser.

So far I have tried something like this

```
        string authenticate 
          = @"http://www.mindmeister.com/services/auth/?" 
               + api_key=abc123&perms=delete&api_sig=zxy987";
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(authenticate);
        @"https://www.mindmeister.com/account/login");
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        //response.ResponseURI == @"https://www.mindmeister.com/account/login"

        WebRequest request2 = WebRequest.Create(response.ResponseUri);
        request2.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
        HttpWebResponse response2 = (HttpWebResponse)request2.GetResponse();
```

but this does not work.

Can I get some guidance on how to accomplish what I want? I have next to no experience with WebRequest or HttpWebResponse as I basically just copied and pasted other solutions on StackOverflow.

Comment: What does, "this does not work" mean?  Are you getting an exception, timeout, etc?

Comment: Once I try to actually call the REST APIs that require authentication, it starts throwing exceptions. If I copy and paste the authentication URL into my browser and login manually, then I can continue with the application and call all the REST APIs I want without issue.

Comment: Maybe if you provide us with the exceptions that you're getting we can help you identify the problem.

Comment: The types of exceptions I'm getting are things like null reference exceptions. For example, if I'm trying to call a REST API which is supposed to pull my mind maps from my MindMeister account, I'm getting back nothing. To me, this means that it did not recognize me logging into MindMeister with my second WebRequest. But like I said before, if I manually navigate to the authentication url and login, I do get back my mind map data.

Comment: You're not getting any kind of web exceptions?  That is, the web request returns, but the response is null?  Is that right?  Generally a web request doesn't fail without some kind of exception being thrown (e.g. can't connect, server exception, etc.).  Are you sure you're even getting to MindMeister?  You could try using Fiddler or something to see if your request is actually going out and what response your getting from the server (if you get there).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation it appears that login this way is not officially supported. Keep in mind that most services that operate using an API key can and will revoke this key if they don't like the way it's being used.

However the login might not be needed every time a user starts your application.

It appears that if you get a `frob` using the `mm.auth.getFrob` method and pass that as a parameter with the login you could then use that same `frob` on the `mm.auth.getToken` method.
You can then store this token somewhere on the users desktop and could use this to use methods in the future.

This should keep working until the user actively revokes the permissions to your application.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks for the help! I guess for now I will just force the user to log in manually before starting the app and use the frob method to retain access to the account between sessions